# How can I keep my For /F updated while I carry out other things in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a chat room for me and my friends and I was wondering if there was a way to keep my For /F "Delims" up to date while I carry out other programs.

```
:Chat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (Chat.txt)  Do (
Set Chat=%%A
)
```

And at the same time I want to be able to do this:

```
set/p input=-
echo %input% >> Chat.txt
```

Is this possible and if it is how?

Comment: what if you put the two bits each in different batch files and then use start to each of them run them without waiting for the other?

Comment: Most effecient way of doing this is two windows. You could make it that the page would refresh every second unless they started typing using `choice`. But I will just check other alternatives.

Comment: How do you use choice? Monacraft

Comment: Type `choice /?` for more info.

Comment: you could use `waitfor` to synchronize both windows.

Comment: FOR /F buffers the entire content of Chat.txt before iterating any of the lines. So it is impossible for FOR /F to see changes to Chat.txt that occur after the loop begins.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better if you put that inside of a goto loop, like this (if statement optional)?

```
:Chat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (Chat.txt)  Do (
Set Chat=%%A
)
if %= condition =%
goto :Chat
)
```